# TYPO3 Symfony Dependency Injection Constructor with runtime arguments and classes

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, typo3

Is it possible to define a constructor which handels runtime arguments and dependeny injection at once? If i do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    protected array $runtimeArg;

    public function __construct(
        array $runtimeArg,
        private readonly NewsRepository $newsRepository
    )
    {
        $this->runtimeArg = $runtimeArg;
    }
}

$myClass = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyClass::CLASS, []);
```

I get:
Cannot autowire service "..MyClass": argument "$runtimeArg" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you should configure its value explicitly.

Comment: Where do you provide an array for the input parameter?

Comment: I rewrote it for StackOverlow. Originally it was an array. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your class should be like this:

```
class MyClass {
    protected array $runtimeArg;

    public function __construct(
        array $runtimeArg,
        private readonly NewsRepository $newsRepository
    )
    {
        $this->runtimeArg = $runtimeArg;  // Fix the typo here
    }
}

// using array while creating instance 
$myClass = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyClass::CLASS, ['foo']);
```

Comment: I rewrote it for StackOverlow. Originally it was an array. I fixed it. The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor has scalar values, you need to define the values in the `Services.yaml` to be set there directly (string, int, bools, ....).

Using the `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` will dispatch to the symfony DI container for wiring things - as long as it's possible.

On the otherhand, as soon as you provide any arguments to the GeneralUtility::makeInstance() call beside the class name, the DI is not used at all [1] and a simple instance created passing all provided arguments as constructor arguments [2] .. which means that you have to provide all arguments directly.

So, there is no way in having a mix with the constructor and having some things autowired and some not. If you still want to create a instance and provide the `$runtimeArg` on creation, you need to get the repository and provide all constructor arguments:

```php
class MyClass {
    protected array $runtimeArg;

    public function __construct(
        array $runtimeArg,
        private readonly NewsRepository $newsRepository
    )
    {
        $this->runtimeArg = $runtimeArg;  // Fix the typo here
    }
}

// using array while creating instance 
$myClass = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
  MyClass::class,
  // provide all MyClass::__construct() arguments directly to be used
  ['foo' => 'value'],
  GeneralUtility::makeInstance(NewsRepository::class)
);
```

which avoids the DI for creating a `MyClass` instance but still using DI to get a fully auto-wired `NewsRepository` instance for the constructor.

If the runtime arguemts are not needed to be provided dynamically on the makeInstance() call, you could define them in the `Services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  /* basic extension default snippet */

  MyVendor\MyExt\MyClass:
    public: true
    arguments:
      $runtimeArgs:
        key1: 'value1'
        key2: 'value2'
```

and than using simply

```php
$myClass = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyClass::class);
```

Another approach would be to create a factory arround your class and use the factroy from makeInstance:

```php
class MyClass {
    protected array $runtimeArg;

    public function __construct(
        array $runtimeArg,
        private readonly NewsRepository $newsRepository
    )
    {
        $this->runtimeArg = $runtimeArg;  // Fix the typo here
    }
}

class MyClassFactory {
  public function __construct(
    private readonly NewsRepository $newsRepository
  ) {}

  public function create(array $runtimeArgs): MyClass
  {
    return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
      MyClass::class,
      $runtimeArgs,
      $this->newsRepository
    );

    // or

    return new MyClass(
      $runtimeArgs,
      $this->newsRepository
    );
  }
}

$runtimeArgs = [
  'key1' => 'value1',
];
GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyClassFactory::class)
  ->create($runtimeArgs);
```

---

Code Snippet [1] https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/7c6b5cc7acff9fbcef13c2a28d5997b654201a28/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php#L2782

```php
// Read service and prototypes from the DI container, this is required to
// support classes that require dependency injection.
// We operate on the original class name on purpose, as class overrides
// are resolved inside the container
if (self::$container !== null
    && $constructorArguments === []
    && self::$container->has($className)
) {
  return self::$container->get($className);
}
```

---

Code Snippet [2] https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/7c6b5cc7acff9fbcef13c2a28d5997b654201a28/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php#L2787

```php
// Create new instance and call constructor with parameters
$instance = new $finalClassName(...$constructorArguments);
```